# Error Deploying WAR file via jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, war, wildfly-8, jboss-cli

I am trying to deploy a war file using jboss-cli to Wildfly 8.

The command I'm using is as follows,

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect --command="deploy --force E:\Projects\CD&CI\portal.war"
```

That gives me an exception like below,

```
org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:278)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:253)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineException: The controller is not available at localhost:9990
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:1020)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:832)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:811)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:276)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:997)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:169)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient$2.getChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:129)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127)
        ... 13 more
```

I also tried changing `jboss-cli.xml`'s default controller to 9999 where it takes protocol as `remote` instead of it's default value `http-remote`, but nothing worked.

I tried to connect to the jboss management console, but it also didn't work.

```
jboss-cli.bat -c
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a native-interface instead of a http-interface so it won't use the correct protocol.

I had to change the management interface in standalone-full.xml file as below.

```
<management-interfaces><!--
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http" />
            </http-interface>-->
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}" secure-port="${jboss.management.http.port:9993}"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
```